# How can I configure additional eclipse settings with m2eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse, maven-eclipse-plugin

With the maven eclipse plugin, I can configure [checkstyle](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/configure-checkstyle.html) or sonar configurations by adding the necessary invocations to the pom.xml and calling "mvn eclipse:eclipse" to create the project configuration.

Some members of my team want to just use "Import Maven project" and therefore don't get the benefits of the project preconfigurations. Is there a way to provide the same (or similiar) hints to m2eclipse?

What I want to accomplish is that people simply "Import Maven Project", and they automatically get a project preconfigured with the correct checkstyle configuration (which is possibly downloaded from somewhere as defined in the POM) without having to manually go into the project preferences and click around a lot. That somehow defeats the purpose of automatic project generation :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more detailed answers to this topic in [Can I Configure m2eclipse through pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4122308/624220): Completely automatic configuration can only be achieved with a ProjectConfigurator. But there is a solution based on AntRun and XMLTask even for FindBugs and Sonar. It needs manual triggering only once after checkout.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable by writing custom [ProjectConfigurator](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/ProjectConfigurator+contributor+guide) (as mentioned in this [thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Preparing-for-M2Eclipse-1-0-no-support-for-the-maven-eclipse-plugin-td139921.html)). And it looks like somebody plublished some of them (for Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs) in the [m2e-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/m2e-extensions/) project.