# In the Eclipe PMD plugin, can I reference the standard ruleset files?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, pmd

I would like my [eclipse PMD plugin](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse/) configuration to access the same [standard ruleset files](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/index.html) as the [maven-pmd-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html).

You can configure the maven pmd plugin to use a custom set of rule sets like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <rulesets>
        <!-- Two rule sets that come bundled with PMD -->
        <ruleset>/rulesets/braces.xml</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/naming.xml</ruleset>
        <!-- Custom local file system rule set -->
        <ruleset>d:\rulesets\strings.xml</ruleset>
        <!-- Custom remote rule set accessed via a URL -->
        <ruleset>http://localhost/design.xml</ruleset>
      </rulesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but in the eclipse plugin you can only switch on / turn off individual rules or specify a single ruleset file. Is there perhaps a way that ruleset file can include several others? Or do I have to aggregate that file automatically from the rulesets I want to use?

Comment: I'm really curious to see how you'll solve this :)

Comment: Me too. I am something of a hacker, but I'm trying to figure out if I'm crazy enough to pull this off: read the config of the Maven PMD plugin, find the referenced ruleset files, collect their rules and create a .rules file using these rules that eclipse can use. Sounds like me, doesn't it ? :-) This is of course in the context of my m2eclipse question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122308/can-i-configure-m2eclipse-through-pom-xml

Comment: Yes, I figured out recent questions were related to this one. And yes, it definitely does sound like you >:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include other rulesets in a PMD ruleset file, e.g.

```
<ruleset ...>
    ...
    <rule ref="rulesets/basic.xml"/>
    ...
    <rule ref="rulesets/strings.xml">
        <exclude name="AvoidDuplicateLiterals"/>
    </rule>
    ...
</ruleset>
```

This is actually an excerpt from our own ruleset file, so it is proven to work :-)

As you can see, you can exclude/include individual rules from your ruleset, or even reconfigure them. One caveat: **you must not mix rules for different languages in a single ruleset**. I.e. in our case, we had to create separate rulesets for Java and JSP.

I learned the tricks myself from [this page](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/howtomakearuleset.html).

Comment: JSP is evil :-) We use wicket, so there's only Java here (and some minimal HTML)

Comment: @seanizer, ours is a legacy project. In theory I tend to agree with you, but as our GUI is dead simple, we hardly ever need to touch the JSP code. Thus replacing it with something more modern/secure/younameit is not our top priority.