# m2eclipse: How to set Eclipse project settings when importing a maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

Using m2eclipse Eclipse plugin, everybody on the dev team should be able to checkout source code, import Maven project in Eclipse and be [good to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377).

I saw m2eclipse is being merged into Eclipse 3.7, and maven-eclipse-plugin won't be maintained any longer, so I'm looking for a m2eclipse-based solution (without running "mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse" before project import, which is what maven-eclipse-plugin does).

maven-eclipse-plugin allows this in pom.xml

```
<additionalConfig>
<file>
    <name>.settings/com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.prefs</name>
    <content><![CDATA[
        eclipse.preferences.version=2
        jarsExcludedFromWebInfLib=
        warSrcDir=${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}
        warSrcDirIsOutput=true
        ]]>
    </content>
</file>
```

The more general question is How would m2eclipse do something similar?
For some cases, just saving the eclipse .settings/prefs file works (e.g. org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs), but in this case, com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.prefs is always overwritten on m2eclipse project import.

A specific question is [asked here](http://groups.google.com/group/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users/browse_thread/thread/68db6957421a9a05), with no reply.
Thanks!

UPDATE: Not possible now, see [request](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5825)

Answer (score 2):

There are answers to this topic in [Can I Configure m2eclipse through pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4122308/624220): Completely automatic configuration can only be achieved with a ProjectConfigurator. But there is a solution based on AntRun and XMLTask even for the Google Eclipse Plugin GEP. It needs manual triggering only once after checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Try asking your question on m2eclipse forum on eclipse.org. You will likely reach far more people familiar with m2eclipse that way.

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=61

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, I've found out it's not possible now (see the update)