# What exactly is performed by Spring Project Builder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

To be more precisely, I am setting up a Maven project which uses Spring for dependency injection. As I want Maven to add Spring Project nature to my Eclipse project files, I put this into the `maven-eclipse-plugin` part of my `pom.xml`:

```maven
<additionalProjectnatures>
   <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
</additionalProjectnatures>
```

I was not able to find any official documentation on the Spring sites about this Maven setup. Most other sites, e.g. like [this one](http://ahoehma.wordpress.com/2008/04/16/maven-eclipse-spring/) or this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9116690/709431), recommend to put this into the configuration section, too:

```maven
<additionalBuildcommands>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
    </buildCommand>
</additionalBuildcommands>
```

Looking into Eclipse, I see that this builder is also configured. What exactly does this builder do?

Comment: The Spring Nature in my Spring projects in STS get not lost when I do "Maven/Update Project" so there is maybe a problem with your eclipse or pom.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed.  I don't see anything controversial or subjective about it (at least not since it was edited) or it's likely answers, and I, for one, would like to know what the springbuilder does.  Please consider re-opening this question.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your support. I do not know what I can do to request a re-opening. I already edited this question but nothing happened since then. Sorry.