# How to import M2Eclipse project with specific nature

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

When importing a maven project with M2Eclipse, M2Eclipse will configure the project by creating the .project, .settings and .classpath files. Is there a possiblity to configure M2Eclipse to add some specefic project natures to the .project file?

While searching for a solution, I found this question from 2011:
[Can I Configure m2eclipse through pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122308/can-i-configure-m2eclipse-through-pom-xml)

Is there a recommended way now?

Comment: I don't think anything has changed since 2011. Which nature would you like to have?

Comment: It's the sap webapp nature: com.sap.ide.ui5.app.plugin.webappnature